# Android удалить все фрагменты

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как удалить все фрагменты?

Пробовал так:

```
for (Fragment fragment: fragmentmanager.getFragments()) {
      fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

Пробовал и так:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Во втором варианте вообще ничего не происходит.

В первом варианте, они реально удаляются с активити, но проверка их наличия возвращает, что они есть:

```
if (fragmentmanager.findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
}
```

Да и если просто проверить  fragmentmanager.getFragments() после удаления, то он будет полон фрагментами.

Я хочу удалить историю всех фрагментов с активити и загрузить только один фрагмент.

Просто replace использовать нельзя, будет конфликт того что данный фрагмент уже загружен.

Comment: Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Вопрос был задан давно - удалось ли найти решение?